# typescript + babel + es6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am a bit confused what to do in the setup of my environement.

should I set my target to es6 in tsconfig, or is it the babel config that works.
Also if I want to use promises, is it then still the same setup, and then I also add babel-polyfill ?

I want my code to run in IE.
I use typescript 2
I use babel

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/"]
  }
}
```

EDIT
I ended removing babel and just using typescript and a polyfill. I use this polyfill https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-promise

for anyone interested here is my webpack setup.
It runs typescript compiling and SCSS.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const SimpleProgressPlugin = require('webpack-simple-progress-plugin');


//*************PLUGINS***************All called in bottom of file***************************************/
// List of vendor JS libraries we want in a seperate vendor.js file
const VENDOR_LIBS = [ // this takes our vendor js files that we want in a seperate file
  "jquery",
  "lodash"
];

// Extract styles
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles.[contenthash].css'
});

// Clean our build folder
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const cleanConfig = new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build/*'], {
  root: '',
  verbose: true,
  dry: false,
  exclude: ['example.js']
})

// if we e.g. import jquery in our code, and also has it in our vendor.js file, remove them from our output bundle code, and only include it in vendor.js
const optimize = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor'
});

const promisePolyfill = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Promise: 'es6-promise-promise'
});

const html = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ //Automaticly make index.html for us, and use our own index.html as a template. This means that it will only fill out what we didn't add. Fx our stylesheet and javascript files.
  template: './src/index.html'
});

const progress = new SimpleProgressPlugin(
  {
    messageTemplate: ['Thinking   :bar', chalk.bold.bgBlue.yellow(':elapsed sec'), ':msg'].join(' '),
    progressOptions: {
      complete: chalk.bgGreen(' '),
      incomplete: chalk.bgWhite(' '),
      width: 20,
      total: 100,
      clear: false
    }
  }
);


//*************WEBPACK CONFIG***************************************************************/
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/index.ts', // Our whole codebase starts here. Our bundle will be called "bundle"
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS // Our vendors, and output file will be named "vendor"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js' // output bundle.js and vendor.js
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractSass.extract({
          use: [{
            loader: "css-loader", options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader", options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ // Our plugin from the top, are called here
    progress,
    promisePolyfill,
    extractSass,
    cleanConfig,
    optimize,
    html
  ]
};
```

Comment: If you are using TS, it is unlikely that you would need to worry  about Babel.

Comment: what about new stuff like promises

Comment: Promises are not new. Anyway, if you need to run in some really old environment without native promises, use a polyfill.

Comment: ok. So it is better just to skip babel and just use typescript and polyfills ?

Comment: I would say yes. Babel's purpose in life is to transpile, which TS already does.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would use both babel and Typescript...  If you're wanting to use promises is a browser that doesn't support them OOB, then use a polyfill  (I use the npm [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/ES6-Promise))  It has [Type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) so everything works smoothly in TypeScript.

Comment: hi
now I have played around with it for some time today, and you are completely right. I have removed babel from my setup, and just use typescript and a polyfill.

I guess it was a mixture of many different tutorials and articles, that made me believe I needed both :)

Comment: I have updated my question and provided my final setup